# How to use a line break in eqnarray without adding a new equation number?

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking, labels, eqnarray

I am working on a two-columned page and want to write a long formula. I want to use `eqnarray` so that I can label my equations and refer to them. Not working with `eqnarray`, I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{times,latexsym, amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts, url, fontenc, tacl2021v1, xspace,mfirstuc,tabulary}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{rl}
        $V$ & The set of unique words in the corpus.\\
        & $V = \{w_{i}|~ i\in \{1,2,...|V|\};$\\
        &$w_{i} \neq w_{j} \forall i,j \in \{1,2,...|V|\} \}$.\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Which shows as:

[image]

However, I want to label this equation to refer to it later. To do so, I have used the following code:

```
The set of unique words in the corpus $V$.\\
\begin{eqnarray}
    V = \{w_{i}|~ i\in \{1,2,...|V|\};\\
    w_{i} \neq w_{j} \forall i,j \in \{1,2,...|V|\} \}
\end{eqnarray}
```

However, this assigns a new label to the new line:

[image]

How can I use a linebreak and only one label in my equation?

Comment: Maybe `\nonumber`? Also, consider using `align` instead.

Comment: Unrelated use `\dots` instead of `...`, and be very careful then using `|V|`, it is better to use `\lvert V \rvert` or even better `\abs{V}` (see `mathtools` on how to define a good `\abs). The spacing around the set builder `|` is also incorrect.

Comment: Why do you need the second line at all? Sets by definition don't have duplicate elements. You can just use `\begin{equation} V = \bigl\{w_{i}\mid i\in \{1,2,\dots,\lvert V\rvert\}\bigr\} \end{equation}`. Note the use of `\mid` and `\dots`.

Comment: @SandyG, some of the collections in my paper can have duplicates, and some are true sets, so I need to show the difference. I could use another symbol to reflect a collection instead of a set, but I am unaware of such a symbol. Do you have suggestions?

Comment: See [here](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-eqnarray) for why you should never use eqnarray.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `eqnarray` for any reason.

Depending on where you want to place the equation number, choose from one of the two examples below.

Since you seem to need to split the equation, I assume you're typesetting in two-column format.

Note the (important) changes I made to the code.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

The set of unique words in the corpus $V$
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    V = \{ & w_{i}\mid i\in \{1,2,\dots,|V|\};\\
           & w_{i} \neq w_{j}, \forall i,j \in \{1,2,\dots,|V|\} \}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

The set of unique words in the corpus $V$
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}[b]
    V = \{ & w_{i}\mid i\in \{1,2,\dots,|V|\};\\
           & w_{i} \neq w_{j}, \forall i,j \in \{1,2,\dots,|V|\} \}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option could be `multline`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

The set of unique words in the corpus $V$
\begin{multline}
    V = \{ w_{i}\mid i\in \{1,2,\dots,|V|\};\\
           w_{i} \neq w_{j}, \forall i,j \in \{1,2,\dots,|V|\} \}
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

[image]